# R WebSocket connection works, but not receiving any messages

Tags: r, node.js, api, websocket

I am trying to use R to replicate the following NodeJS WebSocket script, and I am managing to establish a connection with the server, however I am not receiving back any messages with the appropriate data that I would like. For context, I am using FinancialModelingPrep's websocket service to stream real-time stock prices. Here is the NodeJS script I am trying to replicate:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://websockets.financialmodelingprep.com', null, null, null, {rejectUnauthorized: false});

const login = {
    'event':'login',
    'data': {
        'apiKey': "<apiKey>",
    }
}

const subscribe = {
    'event':'subscribe',
    'data': {
        'ticker': "aapl",
    }
}

ws.on('open', function open() {
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(login));
  ws.send(JSON.stringify(subscribe));
});

ws.on('message', function(data, flags) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

Here is my attempt to replicate it in R using the 'websocket' library:

```
login <- list(
  'event' = 'login',
  'data' = list(
    'apiKey' = "<apiKey>"
  )
)

subscribe <- list(
  'event' = 'subscribe',
  'data' = list(
    'ticker' = "btcusd"
  )
)


unsubscribe <- list(
  'event' = 'unsubscribe',
  'data' = list(
    'ticker' = "btcusd"
  )
)


ws <- websocket::WebSocket$new(
  url = 'wss://crypto.financialmodelingprep.com',
  protocols = character(0),
  headers = NULL,
  autoConnect = F,
  accessLogChannels = c("all"),
  maxMessageSize = 32 * 1024 * 1024
  )

ws$onOpen(function(event) {
  
  cat("Connection opened\n")
  ws$send(toJSON(login))
  cat("Login in then pause...\n")
  Sys.sleep(1)
  ws$send(toJSON(subscribe))
  cat("Subscribe then pause...\n")
  Sys.sleep(1)
  cat("Unsubscribing...\n")
  ws$send(toJSON(unsubscribe))

})

ws$onMessage(function(event) {
  
  cat("Client got msg: ", fromJSON(event$data), "\n")
  
})
ws$onClose(function(event) {
  cat("Client disconnected with code ", event$code,
      " and reason ", event$reason, "\n", sep = "")
})
ws$onError(function(event) {
  cat("Client failed to connect: ", event$message, "\n")
})

ws$connect()
```

When I run the R script to connect, I receive the "connection opened" message as well as the logging in, subscribing and unsubscribing messages. However, it seems as if the onMessage part is never triggered. Below is the output that I receive from the server:

```
Connection opened
Login in then pause...
[2022-11-19 12:05:47] [frame_header] Dispatching write containing 1 message(s) containing 6 header bytes and 74 payload bytes
[2022-11-19 12:05:47] [frame_header] Header Bytes: 
[0] (6) 81 CA DF B7 07 F8 

[2022-11-19 12:05:47] [frame_payload] Payload Bytes: 
[0] (74) [1] ��b���s���%���n���+ڻ�s���|ھ�n���%�0���4��aλ�aͻ�4��2���a���4���%���

Subscribe then pause...
[2022-11-19 12:05:48] [frame_header] Dispatching write containing 1 message(s) containing 6 header bytes and 52 payload bytes
[2022-11-19 12:05:48] [frame_header] Header Bytes: 
[0] (6) 81 B4 05 00 D3 E9 

[2022-11-19 12:05:48] [frame_payload] Payload Bytes: 
[0] (52) [1] ~"��`n��?[�pb��wi��']��aa��':��qi��`r��^"��fu��']��

Unsubscribing...
[2022-11-19 12:05:49] [frame_header] Dispatching write containing 1 message(s) containing 6 header bytes and 54 payload bytes
[2022-11-19 12:05:49] [frame_header] Header Bytes: 
[0] (6) 81 B6 E1 AF 95 38 

[2022-11-19 12:05:49] [frame_payload] Payload Bytes: 
[0] (54) [1] ���N������M���Z���Q�ʷe͍�Y�η���Q���JÕ����M�˷e��
[2022-11-19 12:06:49] [error] handle_read_frame error: websocketpp.transport:7 (End of File)
[2022-11-19 12:06:49] [disconnect] Disconnect close local:[1006,End of File] remote:[1006]
Client disconnected with code 1006 and reason
```

Lastly, here is the output I am supposed to receive (according to FinancialModelingPrep's documentation):

```
wss://crypto.financialmodelingprep.com
{
  "s": "btcusd",
  "t": 16487238632060000000,
  "e": "binance",
  "type": "Q",
  "bs": 0.00689248,
  "bp": 47244.8,
  "as": 1.72784126,
  "ap": 47244.9
}
```

I have a feeling I'm doing something wrong.. I am out of ideas on how to achieve the above output using R, and unfortunately I am not experienced enough to do it via NodeJS. Any help would be appreciated.